# Draw a cross in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF Control.

I need to have in background a cross, like this:
[image]

After that, I'd be able to add other controls over my "crossed" background:
[image]

How should I draw the cross, knowing that when I rezize the control, the cross should follow its size?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quick and dirty way is to use lines and bind their coordinates to the width and height of some parent container. Something like this:

```
<Grid Name="parent">
    <Line  X1="0" Y1="0" X2="{Binding ElementName='parent', Path='ActualWidth'}" Y2="{Binding ElementName='parent', Path='ActualHeight'}" 
           Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" />
    <Line  X1="0" Y1="{Binding ElementName='parent', Path='ActualHeight'}" X2="{Binding ElementName='parent', Path='ActualWidth'}" Y2="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" />
</Grid>
```

Using a grid as the parent means any other children added to the grid after the lines will appear on top of the lines:

```
<Grid Name="parent">
    <Line  X1="0" Y1="0" X2="{Binding ElementName='parent', Path='ActualWidth'}" Y2="{Binding ElementName='parent', Path='ActualHeight'}" 
           Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" />
    <Line  X1="0" Y1="{Binding ElementName='parent', Path='ActualHeight'}" X2="{Binding ElementName='parent', Path='ActualWidth'}" Y2="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" />
    <Label Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">My Label</Label>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 10):

Rather than creating two elements for the layout engine, you can use a single `Path` item:

```xml
<Path Data="M0,0L16,16M16,0L0,16" Stroke="Black" />
```

This is a 16x16 "X" symbol:

[image]

You can specify a different size in the `Data` element, or use a `ViewBox` to scale it to its parent size if needed.

Note that the line ends are square, and slightly extend beyond the 16x16 square:

[image]

If you want the box to be exactly 16x16, you can set `Width="16" Height="16"` on the `Path`, which clips the line ends:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Another way to solve this is to just put everything in a `Viewbox` and use `Stretch="fill"`.  It will handle re-sizing for you while maintaining the proper proportions.  You won't need to use databinding in this case.

```
<Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill">
        <Grid>
            <Line  X1="0" Y1="0" X2="100" Y2="100" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
            <Line  X1="0" Y1="100" X2="100" Y2="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
    <Label Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">My Label</Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: One thing to be aware of with using the ViewBox is that it will zoom the thickness of the lines as well (i.e. as you resize your window, the lines will get thicker). Whether or not this is desirable, is a separate question.

Comment: @MattBurland That's true.  Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Saved my day. Thank you @BojinLi

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Matt Burland made my app constantly blinking (cause I suppose the reference to 'parent' resized it ... and then resized the lines, etc ...)

So I used Stretch=Fill and suppressed the reference to 'parent'. Works pretty fine now.

```
<Line x:Name="Line1" Visibility="Hidden" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" Stretch="Fill"
                X1="0" Y1="0" X2="1" Y2="1" />
<Line x:Name="Line2" Visibility="Hidden" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" Stretch="Fill"
                X1="0" Y1="1" X2="1" Y2="0" />
```

This is a mix from this solution and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846697/draw-diagonal-line-in-wpf-grid/31358487#31358487)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <Line  X1="10" Y1="10" X2="50" Y2="50" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" />
    <Line  X1="10" Y1="50" X2="50" Y2="10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" />
```

if you wonder where the x and y values come, just draw out Cartesian coordinates and plug in

```
line 1 - point 1:(10,10), point 2:(50,50)
line 2 - point 1:(10,50), point 2:(50,10)
```

ref on shapes
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx

put the label after/below the Line elements in XAML, that will make it draw over the lines

Comment: BTW, I just noticed your name, I am originally from Chisinau, small world, anyway, hope this gets you started

Answer (score 0):

Use StreamGeometry and create it as code behind. The example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-shape-using-a-streamgeometry?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) shows how to create StreamGeometry in code.

An "M" in the stream would be "BeginFigure" in code. Then there's LineTo, ArcTo and more. Create a stream, assign it to the Path and you can generate code without having to convert to a string and then back again.