# Add 2 diagonals lines before my Button

Tags: wpf, button, visibility

I want to implement button that after `Mouse Enter` 2 new `Buttons` appear, i can do that with only change the `Visibility` property but i want to 2 new `Button` will appears with diagonal `Lines`:

[image]

Any suggestions how to achieve that ?

Comment: Is this just a single case or should the solution be prepared for the need to show more buttons with diagonal lines after clicking button3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple possible ways of achieving this:

[Draw Diagonal Line in WPF Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846697/draw-diagonal-line-in-wpf-grid)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/1b390e5b-990d-448f-a3b3-e855e0c7ec3e/diagonal-lines-pattern

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms747393(v=vs.100).aspx